# While-loop doesn't work when more elements are added

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a while loop that compares elements from two different lists in each if-elif statement and appends the indices when all the criteria are met. This code works but when I add two more if-elif statements, it doesn't and I'm not sure why.

This code works:

```
i = 0
while i < len(startDate):
    j = 0
    while j < len(stopDate) and i < len(startDate):
        if startDate[i] != stopDate[j]:
            j += 1
        elif startDate[i] == stopDate[j]:
            if stopTime[j] < startTime[i]:
                j += 1
            elif stopTime[j] > startTime[i]:
                if startBehavior[i] != stopBehavior[j]:
                    j += 1
                elif startBehavior[i] == stopBehavior[j]:
                    interval.append(i)
                    interval.append(j)
                    i += 1
```

This code does not:

```
    i = 0
while i < len(startDate):
    j = 0
    while j < len(stopDate) and i < len(startDate):
        if startDate[i] != stopDate[j]:
            j += 1
        elif startDate[i] == stopDate[j]:
            if stopTime[j] < startTime[i]:
                j += 1
            elif stopTime[j] > startTime[i]:
                if startBehavior[i] != stopBehavior[j]:
                    j += 1
                elif startBehavior[i] == stopBehavior[j]:
                    if startInitiator[i] != stopInitiator[j]:
                        j += 1
                    elif startInitiator[i] == stopInitiator[j]:
                        if startReceiver[i] != stopReceiver[j]:
                            j += 1
                        elif startReceiver[i] == stopReceiver[j]:
                            interval.append(i)
                            interval.append(j)
                            i += 1
```

Comment: start by simplifying statements like `if startBehavior[i] != stopBehavior[j]:
                    j += 1
                elif startBehavior[i] == stopBehavior[j]:` => `if startBehavior[i] != stopBehavior[j]:
                    j += 1
                else:`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'd go for `if startBehavior[i] != stopBehavior[j]: j += 1 continue if:` so no more indent than the first if no matter how many if are added

Comment: What happens if `stopTime[i] == startTime[j]`? Shouldn't you have `stopTime[j] *<=* startTime[i]` where you have `stopTime[j] < startTime[i]` ? You'll loop indefinitely if the two are equals because of this. To avoid this kind of problem, use `for` instead of while when looping over list.

Comment: Doesn't work how? what's the error?

Comment: @MoxieBall it just won't run

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a much cleaner way to write your code is :

```
i = 0
while i < len(startDate) and j < len(stopDate):
    j = 0
    if startDate[i] == stopDate[j] and startBehavior[i] == stopBehavior[j] and \
       startInitiator[i] == stopInitiator[j] and startReceiver[i] == stopReceiver[j] and \
       stopTime[j] > startTime[i]:
           interval.append(i)
           interval.append(j)
               i += 1
    else:
        j+=1
```

Tell us if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting it in a more "pythonic" way (even if data restructuration might improve quality) :

```
def criteria_respected(startDate, stopDate, startTime, stopTime,
                       startBehavior, stopBehavior, startInitiator,
                       stopInitiator, startReceiver, stopReceiver):
    if startDate != stopDate:
        return False
    if startTime >= stopTime:
        return False
    if startBehavior != stopBehavior:
        return False
    if startInitiator != stopInitiator:
        return False
    if startReceiver != stopReceiver:
        return False
    return True

interval = list()
for i in range(len(startDate)):
    for j in range(len(stopDate)):
        if criteria_respected(startDate[i], stopDate[j], startTime[i], stopTime[j], startBehavior[i], stopBehavior[j], startInitiator[i], stopInitiator[j], startReceiver[i], stopReceiver[j]):
            interval.append(i)
            interval.append(j)
```

I can't test it without your input.

**The problem might be you only increase  `i` when all condition are met, if they never met, endless loop. If they do met, you don't `[i][j+1]`**

Also ">=" on the second condition, that may have made you loop indefinitely on specific dataset. Did you have the same dataset for both versions?

If it doesn't work, can you give us the input and output wanted?